# UserProfile table to delete user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 and VS_2012. I want to delete a user my admin panel.
I usually delete this way;

UsersContext dcUser = new UsersContext();

```
if (userId.HasValue)
 {
     var userToDelete = (from u in dcUser.UserProfiles
                         where u.UserId == userId
                         select u).Single();

  //   dcUser.UserProfiles.DeleteOnSubmit(userToDelete);
 //   dcUser.SubmitChanges();
  }
```

But this case I can't access DeleteOnSubmit and SubmitChanges.
Is there any way to delete user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
dcUser.Entry<string>(userToDelete).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
```

Comment: dcUser.Entry<UserProfile>(userToDelete).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;

I used it but it didn't work

Comment: By saying *it did not work* you mean that you got an exception or that the entity was not deleted? Did you call the `.SaveChanges()` method on your context after setting the state?

Comment: Yes i used SaveChages() but was there an exception : "DBUpdateException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: Are there some details about this exception? Have you checked the InnerException?

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"fk_UserId\". The conflict occurred in database \"XXX\", table \"dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles\", column 'UserId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

I think i must delete webpages_UsersInRoles table's row.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
{
    var tmpuser = "";
    var ctx = new UsersContext();
    using (ctx)
    {
        var firstOrDefault   = ctx.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(us => us.UserId==id);
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
            tmpuser = firstOrDefault.UserName;
    }

    string[] allRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(tmpuser);
    Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(tmpuser,allRoles);

    ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount(tmpuser);
    Membership.Provider.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);
    Membership.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);

    ctx = new UsersContext();

    return View(ctx.UserProfiles.OrderBy(user => user.UserName).ToList());
}
```